# How to use labelOverwrite in v:page.languageMenu

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-6.2.x

I have labels like en-us, en-uk. BUt for the v:page.languageMenu I would like to use other labels.

In the documentation:
https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/1.3.1/Page/LanguageMenuViewHelper.html

There is a "function" labelOverwrite, but I can't find any example on how to use it.

Comment: noone knows how to use `labelOverwrite` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/vhs/blob/development/Classes/ViewHelpers/Page/LanguageMenuViewHelper.php#L214), `labelOverwrite` accepts a comma-separated string in the order the languages are used. So if your language menu has en-us and en-uk in this order, you could use

```
labelOverwrite="American English,British English"
```

Comment: thanks alot. I have not found any docu or anything on the internet about this.